# Collatz conjecture generalization

Tags: prime-numbers, arithmetic, collatz-conjecture

I'm studying the collatz conjecture and I arrived at the following generalization:
Given any prime p, take any integer n and apply the following process:
If n is divisible by any prime smaller than p, than n must be divided by this prime until it is no longer divisible.
Else n is multiplied by p and added to 1 until n becomes a number divisible by some prime smaller than p.
The hypothesis is that for any p and any n, if the algorithm is applied a different number is times, n will eventually reach 1.
I tested this hypothesis with a small number of primes and composite integers and it seems to hold. I used the following algorithm in Python:

```
def isPrime(n):
    j=2
    while j<n:
        if n%j==0:
            return False
        else:
            j+=1
    return True     
def prime(n):
    i=2
    j=1
    if n==1:
        return i
    else:
        while isPrime(i)==False or j<n:
            i+=1
            if isPrime(i)==True:
                j+=1
    return i
def smallerPrime(p):
    if isPrime(p)==False:
        return print("this function only acctepts primes")
    p-=2
    while isPrime(p)==False:
            p-=2
    return p    
def PnTest(x,p):
    i=p
    j=x
    k=0
    v=[]
    while i>3:
        i=smallerPrime(i)
        v.append(i)
    v.append(2)
    while x!=1 and k<500:
        k+=1
        for m in v:
            while x%m==0 and x>=m:
                x=x/m
        if x!=1:
            x=p*x+1
    if x==1:
        print("the integer")
        print(j)
        print("complies with the 3p+1 hypothesis\n")
        return print("ok\n")
    if k>=50:
        print("the integer")
        print(j)
        print("cannot be said to comply with the 3p+1 hypothesis\n")
        print("perhaps due to an insufficient number of submissions to this algorythm\n")
        return print("not ok\n")
    
p1=int(input("type a prime p to test the 3p+1 hypothesis for integers smaller than 20*p and greater than p\n"))
x1=20*p1
x2=p1
while x2<=x1:
    PnTest(x2, p1)
    x2+=1
```

I'm writing here with the internet to find out if anyone has ever formulated a similar hypothesis.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144435/discussion-on-question-by-igor-paulino-collatz-conjecture-generalization); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had answered in a comment but it may be useful to know that for some values ​​of $p$ and $n$ there are several exceptions, for example:

$p=13 \quad $ and $\quad n=19$

$19 \rightarrow 248 \rightarrow 31 \rightarrow 404\rightarrow 101\rightarrow 1314\rightarrow 73\rightarrow 950\rightarrow 19 $

Comment: It's really funny. I couldn't find an exception to p=7 or to p=37, but, for p=23 or p=17 there are a lot of exceptions

Comment: This is a complete answer , isn't it ?

Comment: @Peter I think so, you don't need to list all the exceptions, maybe someone can find a mathematical explanation.

Answer (score 0):

*This is not an answer, but too long for a comment: did I got this correct?*

---

Define some parameter $p>2 \in \mathbb P$ for a specific "generalization".
Then take the next smaller prime as parameter $q$.

With this define a iterable transformation

$$  T(n,p) = \cases { 
            n = 1 & stop \\
            n \gt 1 & $\{n,2..q\} \cdot p+1 \to n $ }
$$
where $ \{n,r\}$ means: extract all factors $r$ from $n \in \mathbb N^+$. Here $r$ might as well denote a range of numbers/primefactors

Comment: Almost, because you have to extract all prime factors q smaller than p UNTIL there are no longer such q factors. I don't know if I understood your transformation, but it seems to extract each prime factor only once, while this factor may appear more than one time in a given integer

Comment: @IgorPaulino - well I wrote "means: extract all factors" ; I thought this would be clear that for instance for the (prime)factor $3$ this means all of its powers....

Comment: Ok, blue I have understood your transformation